# How to change all the values in an Elixir map

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I see that there's an [`update`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Dict.html#update/4) in the Dict module, but what about an `update_all` method that changes all values?

I tried doing this with `Enum.map` but the type changed:

```
iex(6)> Enum.map(%{:a => 2}, fn {k, v} -> {k, v + 1} end)
[a: 3]
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could pipe to `Enum.into(%{})` or use a `for` comprehension, i.e.:

```
iex> for {k, v} <- %{a: 1, b: 2}, into: %{}, do: {k, v + 1}
%{a: 2, b: 3}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also do:

```
iex> Map.new(%{:a => 2}, fn {k, v} -> {k, v + 1} end)
%{:a => 3}
```

But feel like there should be something in the standard library to make this easier (`Map.??(%{:a => 2}, &(&1 + 1))`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea:

```
def update_map map, [head|tail], func do
    update_map(
        Dict.update(map, head, :unknown, func),
        tail,
        func
    )
end


def update_map map, [], _ do
    map
end
```

Then to call it:

```
iex(1)> d = %{:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}
%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
iex(2)> update_map(d, Dict.keys(d), fn v -> v + 1 end)
%{a: 2, b: 3, c: 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me add `Enum.into` into the mix

```
headers
|> Enum.group_by(fn {k, _v} -> k end, fn {_k, v} -> v end)
|> Enum.into(%{}, fn {k, v} -> {k, Enum.join(v, ", ")} end)
```

This turns:

```
[{"cookie", "a"}, {"cookie", "b"}] into %{"cookie", "a, b"}
```